# Command+S At Boot Doesn't Activate Single-User Mode

Tags: snow-leopard, startup, root

10.6.8. Hold down Cmd+S throughout the entire boot process. It always goes to the regular login screen and starts doing the "stop holding down buttons" chime. Why?

Comment: This question should be marked as resolved. One way you could do this is post the solution yourself and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. I'd changed my keyboard layout to Dvorak which apparently isn't honored at boot, defaulting to QWERTY. I pressed Cmd+O (where the S would've been) and it worked.